# Can't install discord.net - Failed to retrieve information about 'Discord.Net.Core' from remote source

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, discord.net

I have made Python discord bots in the past with `discord.py` but now I am learning C# and I want to try to make one with `discord.net`. When I try to install `discord.net` - I click on `dependencies`, then NuGet packages, and then browse and search up `discord.net`. When I press the install button, I get the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Failed to retrieve information about 'Discord.Net.Core' from remote source 'https://github.com/DSharpPlus/DSharpPlus/FindPackagesById()?id='Discord.Net.Core'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: You have to be more clear on what your question is

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The issue is that you have used a private nuget feed.** In that feed, you have `Discord.Net` nuget package but some of its nuget dependencies such as `Discord.Net.Core` do not exist in your private feed. This is the cause of the problem. Remember that nuget dependencies are installed together with the nuget main package. If there is a problem with installing the dependencies, the main package cannot be installed in the project.

[image]

So I suggest you should use `nuget.org` nuget package source.

**Suggestion**

**1)** **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Settings**-->**Package Sources**

check `nuget.org` source and if your VS did not have it, you can add like this.

[image]

**2)** then under manage nuget packages UI, please select `nuget.org` to install that package.

[image]

============================================

**Update 1**

Close VS, delete `nuget.config` under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`.

**Then**, restart VS and then installing nuget packages work well.

Comment: I have followed your steps, my nugget.org box was ticked so I tried to uncheck it and then save then recheck but I still get the same error.

Comment: Quite strange and I did not face the same issue in my side. Please try the following two suggestions: 1) close VS, delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`, also enter project folder, delete `bin` and `obj` folder. Then, restart your project to test again. 2) close VS, delete `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` and then restart your project to test again.

Comment: I have looked in my folders and can't find a `.nuget` anywhere on my pc. I am now very confused. I have re-installed Visual Studio 2019 but the same problem keeps on happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The folder is under your current user's folder.  Or you could use VS UI to clean nuget caches. Enter `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`General`-->`Clear All Nuget Caches`.

Comment: I removed all of the nuget caches from the options then restarted Visual Studio and the problem keeps on giving the same error message. Now I am really stuck.

Comment: delete `nuget.config` file from my suggestion two, did it work?

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me out with this problem. I deleted that file and now it works! You are an awesome person; thanks for helping me!

Comment: You are welcome and if you have any questions about nuget further, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 1):

In win search or in ctrl + R enter %appdata%/NuGet and simply delete Nuget.config (have **backup** before delete) then restart your Visual studio. That's it !
99% it will resolve issue.